# How to get store information in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, how can I get active store information, like store name, line number, etc?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To get information about the current store from anywhere in Magento, use:

```
<?php
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
```

This will give you a Mage_Core_Model_Store object, which has some of the information you need:

```
<?php
$name = $store->getName();
```

---

As for your other question about line number, I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean that you want to know what line number in the code you are on (for error handling, for instance), try:

```
<?php
$line      = __LINE__;
$file      = __FILE__;
$class     = __CLASS__;
$method    = __METHOD__;
$namespace = __NAMESPACE__;
```

Comment: How do you get all the active store codes? I tryed `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getStores(); ` but it only returns the current store.

Comment: I have display Notes in PDP page like, Delivery : 5 to 10 days, how can I change Delivery : 10 to 30 days based on current store. Here i have 2 stores.

Answer (score 153):

**Get store data**

```
Mage::app()->getStore();
```

**Store Id**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

**Store code**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

**Website Id**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
```

**Store Name**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

**Store Frontend Name** (*see @Ben's answer*)

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName();
```

**Is Active**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive();
```

**Homepage URL of Store**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl();
```

**Current page URL of Store**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
```

> All of these functions can be found in class **Mage_Core_Model_Store**
>
> File: **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php**

Comment: how we can get the main store name from adminhtml.while i m using **Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()** using this i m getting 'admin'.

Comment: @gowri, the admin area counts as a separate store (with id 0), if you have an order or anything to work with you can do, for example:         $storeId = $order->getStoreId();                   
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId); 
        $name = $store->getWebsite()->getName();

Comment: How expensive is a call to `Mage::app()->getStore()`? I assume that the store is one of the first globals to be instantiated anyway so this would probably be very cheap. Yes?

Comment: When I call Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); it returns "English" Magento 1.9.2.3 using the demo store data.

Comment: I have display Notes in PDP page like, Delivery : 5 to 10 days, how can I change Delivery : 10 to 30 days based on current store. Here i have 2 stores.

Answer (score 29):

Great answers here. If you're looking for the default view "Store Name" set in the Magento configuration:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. When I call Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); it returns "English" Magento 1.9.2.3 using the demo store data.

Answer (score 9):

Just for information sake, in regards to my need... The answer I was looking for here was:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroup()->getName()
```

That is referenced on the admin page, where one can manage multiple stores... admin/system_store, I wanted to retrieve the store group title...

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 1.9.4.0 and maybe all versions in 1.x use:

Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address');

and the following params, it depends what you want to get:

- general/store_information/name
- general/store_information/phone
- general/store_information/merchant_country
- general/store_information/address
- general/store_information/merchant_vat_number

Answer (score 1):

If You are working on Frontend Then Use:

```
$currentStore=Mage::app()->getStore();
```

If You have store id then use

```
$store=Mage::getmodel('core/store')->load($storeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento Store Id**   : `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();`

**Magento Store Name** : `Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();`

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1:

you can use all of these functions can be found in class `Mage_Core_Model_Store`

File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

**Store Data**

```
Mage::app()->getStore();
```

**Store Id**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

**Store code**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

Magento 2
**Using Block**

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

Using Object Manager

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
 
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

That's it

Answer (score -1):

You can get active store information like this:

```
Mage::app()->getStore();  // for store object
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId;  // for store ID
```