# How to find out what my store ID is?

Tags: magento

How do I figure out what my store view ID's are?

This is required when modifying tables within database.

Comment: Why do you need this store id? If you really need it, get a look into the database in the table core_store.

Comment: @Alexandre You need it for example when inserting products via the API.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713042/how-to-get-store-information-in-magento

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Screenshot to illustrate Jevgeni Smirnov's answer:

[image]

As he said, you should go to *System -> Manage Stores* and click on needed store name in the right column.

Answer (score 8):

When you click on the specific store in Manage stores in the URL bar there should be a parameter like store_id or something like that. This is your store id. Or when in Manage stores screen if you hover over store and the link might be displayed in the right(left) corner of your browser. In the url there is store_id param. This is the easiest I guess.

Or in database there is table: core_store.

Answer (score 7):

Pragmatically you can get the website id, website name, store id, store name and store code like this:

```
<?php
echo "Website ID: " . Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() . "<br/>"; 
echo "Website Name: " . Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName() . "<br/>"; 
echo "Store ID: " . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() . "<br/>"; 
echo "Store Name: ".Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(). "<br/>";
echo "Store code: ". Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()."<br/>";
?>
```

Here is an example looping through all the websites and print all store id and store names you have set up in your Magento:

```
<?php
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            echo $store->getId() ." ".$store->getName()."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the 2nd one ftw!

Answer (score 6):

To get `store_id` from `store_code` use:

```
echo Mage::app()->getStore('store_code')->getId();
```

Answer (score 5):

Look into the **`core_store`** table in the database.

Comment: That's for Magento 1. For Magento 2 look at `store` and `store_website` tables.

Answer (score 1):

you should go to "System -> Manage Stores" and click on needed store view name in the right column. click/hover on this and check url you find store id under url after /store_id/

same as -----  system_store/editStore/store_id/**1**/key/