# Get store name in magento using php

Tags: php, magento

How can I get the store name in magento using php?

For example:

I have two stores in magento:

```
domain.com/store/jp
domain.com/store/en
```

How can I get the store name using php? Can you give me the php code line which returns the store name? either **jp** or **en**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713042/how-to-get-store-information-in-magento

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a store code, you can get it in the following way:

```
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

Answer (score 15):

Just sharing what I found:

**Get store data**

```
Mage::app()->getStore();
```

**Store Home Url**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl();
```

**Store code**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

**Is Active**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive();
```

**Website Id**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
```

**Store Name**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

**Store Id**

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

---

©
Source: [how to get store information in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713042/how-to-get-store-information-in-magento) by @[chapagain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327862/chapagain)