# Check store_id Magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to check which store id is currently active and show something is store id is for example 1

The code I have now is this:

```
<?php if (Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId) == 9): ?>
//code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it always returns the if code, no matter what the store id is. I think the problem is in the "=="check. Could someone tell me what the correct syntax is?

Comment: Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId) 
you getting store id using this?

Comment: yep, the $storeId is defined like this

Comment: $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

Comment: check the added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() == 9): ?>
```

in your case

Comment: thanks, this is the one. Although it is without the ';' behind the getStoreId()

Answer (score 1):

to get current store information use

```
 Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

this will explain more

[how to get store information in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713042/how-to-get-store-information-in-magento)